# Eclipse isn't highlighting syntax for index.class.php

Tags: php, eclipse, syntax-highlighting

I just installed eclipse and started working on an existing project. Thing is, none of my code has syntax highlighting. The file name convention is name.class.php and name.html.php

Any ideas?

Comment: You seem to be implying that it works for files like `name.php`. Is this true? Did you verify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the [Eclipse PDT (PHP Development Tools)](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/) installed alongside Eclipse? The standard install will not support PHP highlighting.

There is no need to uninstall your current version of Eclipse. If you want the PDT, just [follow the instructions at this link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation#Eclipse_3.6_.2F_Helios_.2F_PDT_2.2) (assuming you are using Eclipse 3.6). If you follow those instructions, you will download all the necessary "stuff" to use the PDT. If you have a different version of Eclipse, other instructions are on that same site.

Comment: Do I have to uninstall my current setup or is there just and add-on that I can use?

Comment: @Citizen - No need to uninstall. I updated my answer which links to the way to install PDT from the Eclipse Update site. Hope that helps!